# mockk exception - no answer found for

Tags: kotlin, mockk

using mockk for testing kotlin function.

```kotlin
private val serviceObject = mockk<Service>()
private val serviceToBeTested = ServiceToBeTestd(Service)
        
fun test(){
    when(serviceObject.function1(argument1,argument1))
        .thenReturn(<something>)
}
```

When i try to run it, i get this error:

```
io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: Service(#1).function1(argument1, argument2)
```

Any idea why ?

ServiceToBeTestd is the service to be tested, Service is wired in it:

```
open class ServiceToBeTestd
    constructor(private val service: Service)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are using mockito syntax.

Below is correct syntax for mockk.

```
val car = mockk<Car>()

every { car.drive(Direction.NORTH) } returns Outcome.OK
```

Please update your syntax.

Comment: what is "returns" ? There is no any in Mockk

Comment: its kotlin syntax (so is the code posted by OP)

Comment: @aleksandrbel `every { }` runs the block inside `MockKMatcherScope` and that class defines `any()`.

Comment: i am getting the same error ..